# Select Max() is too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to get the latest date from a column in SQL Server 2016 but it takes near 10 seconds to retrieve this data. The table has over 146 million records.

Combined with other queries that I have to run the code takes over 1 minute to complete.

How can I make this query faster?

```
  DECLARE @MaxDate DATE
  SELECT    @MaxDate = MAX(MyDate)
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  MyTable
```

I have even tried

```
    SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT MyDate, COUNT(*) as TheDate,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY MyDate
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

and it is the same speed

Comment: Google Indexes or buy a faster server/computer.

Comment: Why didn't I think to check that. I need coffee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the max date quickly, then create an index on that column, `(mydate)`.

You should be able to do:

```
select max(mydate)
from t;
```

Or if you want all the rows:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by mydate desc;
```